# Passing string to CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE instead of file-pointer

Tags: php, json

I want to store the headers for CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE in a database instead of
a file.
Is there any way I can pass the headers as a string instead of a
"file-pointer"?

I want:

```
$stringWithHeaders = databaseResult...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $stringWithHeaders)
```

Instead of:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookieHeaders.txt");
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How would passing a string make it put the cookies in a database?

Comment: If you want to provide the cookies as a string, use `CURLOPT_COOKIE`.

Comment: Take a look at this comment in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#118967 It explains how to manage cookies yourself instead of using a file.

Comment: @Barmar I am saving all of the cookies data in database instead of files, sp is there any way to use COOKIEFILE for it?

Comment: No, you can't do it with `COOKIEFILE`, that's specifically for getting cookies from a file.

Comment: @Barmar Actually i tried `CURLOPT_COOKIE` too, but it doesn't works. My cookie is in form is a string.

Comment: If it's not working, you're probably not formatting it correctly. It should be `name=value; name=value; ...`

Comment: @Barmar Oh! Thanks let me check.